# Good prebuilt GNU toolchain for Android?

Tags: android, compiler-construction, android-ndk, cross-compiling, gnu-toolchain

I have currently used the standalone toolchain from Android's NDK, but it seems rather difficult to cross compile programs because the libraries provided in NDK lack a lot of things.

I've built `binutils` using NDK standalone toolchain and it all compiled (although I haven't tested to see if the binaries really work), but when it came to `GCC` it became rather difficult.

I saw a toolchain and sysroot downloadable from [Gnash's website](http://www.gnashdev.org/tools/), but when I tried to run it on my computer it didn't work because the package was simply packaged from its original environment has very poor portability.

I'm wondering if there are other prebuilt GNU toolchains available for building thinsg on Android?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do specifically? Android isn't some generic Linux distro where you can just take any existing Linux application, cross-compile it for ARM and expect it to work. Trying to access parts of the hardware that aren't exposed through the stable NDK APIs is likely not going to work across different devices.

Comment: I just want to build some Linux commandline programs for my own device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only other option I know about is the [Crystax NDK](http://www.crystax.net/en/android/ndk).  Crystax adds some nice stuff like wide character support.  I used Crystax in the early days and didn't have much luck.  It is worth a try.